# How To Include and Use A Category In a Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to include and use [this category](http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/adding-metadata-to-ios-images-the-easy-way/) in my project (lets call it target project). While I want to learn about categories in general, **I do need help including the category specified in the link**. I haven't done this before so I need detailed instructions addressing the four questions and any other essential information:

1. After I copy the project into my Xcode do I need to run it?
2. In my target project do I need to include it as a library or include it some other way?
3. What needs to go in my target project class header file?
4. What needs to go in my target project implementation file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a static library, which I don't believe you are, all of your dependencies must be compiled using the `-all_load` linker flag (see [Technical Q&A QA1490
Building Objective-C static libraries with categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html), or else you will run into the 'Unknown Selector' issue.

Other than that, you simply include the `.h` and `.m` (or .h and .a in the case of a static library) files of the category, and all frameworks that may be required by the category, and you move on with your project.

Comment: The link I provided says it is a category. Is he wrong? I would really like to understand this.

Comment: "The repo contains an XCode project that should compile a nice static library for you to use on your projects..."

Comment: Got it working now. Needed to code sign the static library before building to avoid an error. The "Unknow Selector" issue hit me. Full directions here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html.